# Resolving CSS property for node

Tags: javafx-2

maybe my google-fu is just letting me down today, but i have not been able to find a way to resolve arbitrary properties of nodes in order to obtain a style attribute. For instance, I'd like to be able to ask a node 'What is your value (if any) for -fx-fill?'.

A simple application example: I'd like to build a custom legend for a chart. To do so, I'd have to ask a rendered node for their fill property. I could, of course, use my knowledge of the default-colorN classes and simply look up the fill, but it feels like this would be a very bad approach as is violates the whole idea of CSS.

Thanks in advance.

BTW: JavaFX version is 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to ask a node 'What is your value (if any) for -fx-fill?'

There is no public API for that yet.  It is planned to add such an API in a future release.
See [RT-17293 CSS Style Object Model in Java](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091202).

For the 2.0 and 2.1 release, you could probably find the information using undocumented, deprecated impl_ methods, but I wouldn't advise that.

For now, I'd advise just using [css chart](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm) styling where-ever you can and supplementing it with a sprinkling of dynamic [node.lookup()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup%28java.lang.String%29) code where it is impossible to achieve the styling using css.

Comment: Thank you very much. Looking forward to the new API.