# JavaFx: How to get the corresponding stylesheet for a given style class of a Node?

Tags: css, javafx, stylesheet

I am able to retrive the style class(es) of a JavaFx Node "node" with

```
List<String> styleClasses = node.getStyleClass();
```

This gives me for example the style class "chart-plot-background".

**How can I retrive the corresponding currently active stylesheet entry from the node?**

The Caspian.css file contains the entry

```
.chart-plot-background {
-fx-background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

and I would expect to be able to retrieve this information from the node with at least on of the following code snippets:

A.

```
Style style = node.getStyle();
//is empty
```

B.

```
Parent parent = (Parent) node;
List<String> styleSheets = parent.getStyleSheets();
//... loop through the list and search for the entry...
//however, the list is empty
```

C.

```
List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> cssMetaDataList = node.getCssMetaData();
//... loop through the list and search for the entry...
//however, the property "-fx-background-color" is null
```

**Related old article:**

[Resolving CSS property for node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571466/resolving-css-property-for-node)

points to the bug ticket

http://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091202

**Motivation**

I would like to write a converter from JavaFx charts to scalable vector graphic (*.svg) files. In order to do so I need the active properties of each node, e.g. fill color and stroke-width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a note to start: JavaFX 8 uses `modena.css` by default, not `caspian.css`. Since you are using JavaFX 8 (`getCssMetaData()` was introduced in version 8), you want to refer to `modena.css`, unless you are using a system property switch to use the old user-agent stylesheet.

This is something of a partial answer; digging into exactly how to do this would take more time than I have. This should get you started though. If someone has already done the work figuring this out, they may be able to provide a more complete answer.

`-fx-background-color` is actually a sub-property of `-fx-region-background`, as is hinted in the [CSS reference for `Region`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region). The code snippet

```
    Region node = (Region)root.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
    node.getCssMetaData().stream().filter(p -> p.getProperty().equals("-fx-region-background"))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

produces the output

```
CSSProperty {property: -fx-region-background, converter: javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundConverter@6f457c5c, initalValue: null, inherits: false, subProperties: [CSSProperty {property: -fx-background-color, converter: Paint.SequenceConverter, initalValue: [Ljavafx.scene.paint.Paint;@737bd041, inherits: false, subProperties: []}, CSSProperty {property: -fx-background-insets, converter: InsetsSequenceConverter, initalValue: [Ljavafx.geometry.Insets;@22e4912, inherits: false, subProperties: []}, CSSProperty {property: -fx-background-radius, converter: javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadiiConverter@3d63caf3, initalValue: [Ljavafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;@7980e69f, inherits: false, subProperties: []}, CSSProperty {property: -fx-background-image, converter: URLSeqType, initalValue: null, inherits: false, subProperties: []}, CSSProperty {property: -fx-background-repeat, converter: RepeatStructConverter, initalValue: [Lcom.sun.javafx.scene.layout.region.RepeatStruct;@54d4d836, inherits: false, subProperties: []}, CSSProperty {property: -fx-background-position, converter: LayeredBackgroundPositionConverter, initalValue: [Ljavafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;@24c26d67, inherits: false, subProperties: []}, CSSProperty {property: -fx-background-size, converter: com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.region.LayeredBackgroundSizeConverter@7550f5e, initalValue: [Ljavafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;@791fb535, inherits: false, subProperties: []}]}
```

which, if you dig into a little, you will see contains

```
subProperties: [CSSProperty {property: -fx-background-color, converter: Paint.SequenceConverter, initalValue: [Ljavafx.scene.paint.Paint;@737bd041, inherits: false, subProperties: []}, ...]
```

So the `-fx-background-color` is in there.

The way this works, to the best of my knowledge, is that the `CssMetaData` objects describe how to map the CSS into an actual JavaFX property (an instance of `StyleableProperty`, which is a subclass of `WritableValue`. So if you dig through this, you should be able to figure out that `-fx-region-background` maps to `Region.backgroundProperty()`, and `-fx-background-color` maps to the `fill` property of each element of `Region.getBackground().getFills()`. The code snippet

```
    Background bg = node.getBackground();
    bg.getFills().forEach(fill -> System.out.println(fill.getFill()));
```

produces the output

```
0xf4f4f4ff
```

which I believe is the background color defined in `modena.css` for the `chart-plot-background`.

So if you want to automate this, it seems pretty tricky, albeit possible. You'll need to account for "nested" css meta data, which you can access via `getSubProperties()`. You should then be able to call `getStyleableProperty().getValue()`, and (possibly by reflection) dig into the resulting object to get the values set by the "subProperties".

Good luck...

Complete code I used for testing:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class CssPropertyLookupTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        chart.setAnimated(false);
        Random rng = new Random();

        Series<Number, Number> series = new Series<>();
        for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
            Data<Number, Number> data = new Data<>(x, rng.nextDouble());
            series.getData().add(data);
        }
        chart.getData().add(series);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(400, 20);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(chart, null, null, rect, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Region node = (Region)root.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
        node.getCssMetaData().stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getProperty().equals("-fx-region-background"))
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(System.out::println);

        Background bg = node.getBackground();
        bg.getFills().forEach(fill -> System.out.println(fill.getFill()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is difference between getuserAgentStylehseets vs getStyleSheets?